# How to add more default face highlight colors

Tags: faces, variables, hi-lock

Using (highlight-symbol-at-point) at some point the highlight start repeating colors.

[image: auto highlight cycle restarts]

I find the variable that holds the default face highlight color values in Emacs is:
hi-lock-face-defaults

It holds this value:

```lisp
("hi-yellow" "hi-pink" "hi-green" "hi-blue" "hi-salmon" "hi-aquamarine" "hi-black-b" "hi-blue-b" "hi-red-b" "hi-green-b" "hi-black-hb")
```

I want to add more default colors. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Set variable `hi-lock-face-defaults` to the *names* of the faces you want.

```lisp
(add-to-list 'hi-lock-face-defaults "highlight") ; Add a face (`highlight`).
```

or

```lisp
(setq hi-lock-face-defaults  ; Set to just these 3 faces.
      '("dired-flagged" "highlight" "hi-yellow"))
```

or

```lisp
(setq hi-lock-face-defaults ; Add multiple faces.
      (append '("dired-flagged" "highlight") hi-lock-face-defaults))
```